# How can I do forward declarations in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

Here is my situation: type A wants to have a method that returns a type that is a table of type A entries. Can I do this?

Comment: not making sense as an oracle question.  do you mean accessing oracle with some other language?

Comment: @Randy - Oracle has supported User-Defined Types in SQL since version 8.0 i.e about fifteen years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a pair of SQL Type declarations:

```
SQL> create or replace type a as object
  2      ( attr1 number
  3        , attr2 date )
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type a_nt as table of a
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

Now what we want is a method which returns `A_NT()`.  Hmm, let's see:

```
SQL> alter type a
  2      add member function getme (p1 number) return a_nt
  3  /
alter type a
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04055: Aborted: "A" formed a non-REF mutually-dependent cycle with "A_NT".


SQL>
```

Uh-oh.  We need another approach.  This is the sort of occasion when we should be using inheritance.

```
SQL> create or replace type abstract_a as object
  2      ( attr1 number
  3        , attr2 date )
  4  not final not instantiable
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type a_nt as table of abstract_a
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type a under abstract_a
  2      ( member function getme (p1 number) return a_nt )
  3  instantiable
  4  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

Looks good.  So, we'll add an implementation and then try it out:

```
SQL> create or replace type body a as
  2      member function getme (p1 number) return a_nt
  3      is
  4          l_nt a_nt;
  5      begin
  6          select a(empno, hiredate)
  7          bulk collect into l_nt
  8          from emp
  9          where deptno = p1;
 10          return l_nt;
 11      end;
 12  end;
 13  /

Type body created.

SQL>
```

Let's roll!

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2      v a := a(null, null);
  3      n a_nt;
  4  begin
  5      n := v.getme(50);
  6
  7      for i in n.first()..n.last() loop
  8          dbms_output.put_line(n(i).attr1 ||'::'||to_char(n(i).attr2, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
  9      end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
8085::08-APR-2010
8060::08-APR-2008
8061::27-FEB-2010
8100::

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The bootstrapping is cumbersome but it works.  This may be yet another area where Oracle's OOP implementation is incomplete.  But perhaps it's just a reflection of the fact that is not a good idea.  It took me a while to figure it out, because the underlying model doesn't really make sense.  Although maybe with Real World names it would have become obvious :)

Comment: Oh I agree wholeheartedly that the model is broken and makes no sense and is a waste of my time to write in. This is an assignment, though, and I don't have much of a choice.